# Credit card transaction with REST API

Tags: paypal

I am implementing PayPal transactions on my website through the REST API and want to enable direct credit card processing.  I am currently in Australia where this is not available, however when my website goes live I will be hosting it on a US server and only accepting US dollars for the transactions.  Does this mean I will be able to accept credit card payment on my live website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal account would need to be a US based account.